# NSAttributedString justified text (without stretching words)

Tags: ios, uitextview, nsattributedstring, right-justified

I'm using justified text for my NSAttributedString in my UITextView:

```
var paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()        
paragraphStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignment.Justified;
normalAttributes.setObject(paragraphStyle, forKey: NSParagraphStyleAttributeName)
```

The problem is that it stretches some words in order to achieve the justified alignment, instead of just stretching the spaces between the words. I find this very distracting and know there is a way to do such that words are not stretched, but only the spacing. Below is a screenshot from my app, followed by one from an app with some of the same functionality that also uses justified text and the exact same font.

[image]

[image]

How do I achieve the same effect?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Well, it was just a guess. :( Sorry it didn't work. If you really want to get deeply into this you can just dig into Text Kit and override the layout (that may in fact be what the other app does).

Answer (score 3):

There is a nasty trick which you can use.

You can use a UIWebView and css to do the alignment the way you want.
Here is a sample:

```
NSString *css = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                 @"<html><head><style>body { background-color: white; text-align: %@; font-size: %ipx; color: black;} a { color: #172983; } </style></head><body>",
                 @"justify",
                 11];

NSMutableString *desc = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@",
                         css,
                         @"15 Προσέχετε ἀπὸ τῶν ψευδοπροφητῶν͵ οἵτινες ἔρχονται πρὸς ὑμᾶς ἐν ἐνδύμασι προβάτων͵ ἔσωθεν δέ εἰσι λύκοι ἅρπαγες. 16 ἀπὸ τῶν καρπῶν αὐτῶν",
                         @"</body></html>"];

UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 80, 150, 100)];
[self.view addSubview:webView];
[webView loadHTMLString:desc baseURL:nil];
```

And here is the result:

[image: WebView Text Alignment]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the UIWebView approach is not viable for what I am doing. It has to be a UITextView or a Core Text rendered view.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30300323/justify-text-in-ios-swift-or-objective-c-without-breaking-tracking-kerning-let

Answer (score 1):

You just have to change the hyphenationFactor to 1:

```
textView.layoutManager.hyphenationFactor = 1
```

Comment: hyphenationFactor was deprecated in iOS 13.0. Instead use textView.layoutManager.usesDefaultHyphenation = true