# Justify text by inserting spaces between words, not between characters in iOS UITextView

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, justify, textkit

I am trying to justify some text in a `UITextView`. That's easy enough, except the justification algorithm would insert spaces between characters within one word, rather than insert spaces between words. So, one line in the middle of the paragraph could look like this:

```
A example of some
j u s t i f i e d
text that is wit-
hin some kind  of  
text box in app.
```

But I would like to prohibit spaces from being inserted within words, so:

```
A example of some
justified    text
that  is   within 
some kind of text 
box in app.
```

For a visual representation, see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28884792/nsattributedstring-justified-text-without-stretching-words) which is basically the same problem I'm having (except I'm using English).

This is my code:

```
let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
paragraphStyle.alignment = .justified
paragraphStyle.hyphenationFactor = 1

let textView = UITextView()
let attributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle: paragraphStyle]
textView.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: "some text", attributes: attributes)
```

From the amount of searching that I have done, it looks like I may need to use `Core Text` to do this myself. I am very new to the Apple ecosystem and to swift, so my question is: is there an out-of-the-box way of doing what I need? If not, I would appreciate some help to point me in the right direction to implement this myself.

**EDIT: here is a full example for what I'm seeing:**

```
import SwiftUI
import UIKit

struct JustifiedTextView: UIViewRepresentable {
    let string = "An example of some justified text that is within some kind of text box in app containing some longwords and some other short words. DonMag might have some ideas on how to only apply spacing within words not characters."
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITextView {
        let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        paragraphStyle.alignment = .justified
        paragraphStyle.hyphenationFactor = 1
        let attributes = [
            NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle : paragraphStyle,
            NSAttributedString.Key.font : UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 22)
        ]
        let textView = UITextView()
        textView.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: string, attributes: attributes)
        return textView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextView, context: Context) {
        uiView.text = string
    }
}
```

And I use the above like this:

```
import SwiftUI

struct MyView: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            JustifiedTextView()
            JustifiedTextView()
            JustifiedTextView()
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the result of the above on the iOS Simulatior (iPhone 15 Pro, iOS 17.2):

[image]

Comment: What's wrong with the answers in the other question you linked?

Comment: I do not want to use a WebView in my app, and the other answer suggest something I already have: `hyphenationFactor = 1`

Comment: @DewinDell - justified alignment is a little complex. If there are fewer than two words on a line -- a single word, or one word + a fraction of a hyphenated word -- *and* it is not the last line or followed by a newline character, you get inter-character spacing adjustment. Since justified text tends to reduce readability, you need to ask your self if that is really what you want. If the answer is yes, then you'll need to write your own justification alignment algorithm to get your desired results.

Comment: @DonMag yes, I do really want to do this. You are right, this does happens when there are < two words on the line. I am happy to write my own algorithm but I am not sure how to do that. Do you have any pointers or know of any examples I can look at?

Comment: @DewinDell - head over to Google (or your favorite search engine) and search for `justified text algorithm` ... It's tough to answer questions in the abstract. I don't know what your actual layout looks like (with real-world examples of text strings), so I can't offer any other suggestions -- except, *maybe*, you need to re-think your UI design.

Comment: @DonMag I was hoping that there would be a way to "plug-in" to Apple's rendering of the text instead of turning off justify and adding some spaces in my string.

Comment: @DewinDell - if you edit your post with some real-world text string examples - and include the font, font size, text view frame, etc, that you're using... there is an approach I can look at that *may* give you better results.

Comment: @DonMag apologies for the delayed response. I have added a real example in the post. Very keen to see what you might be able to come up with.

Comment: @DewinDell - are you using `UITextView` because the user will be allowed to type in the field? You *could* try different values for `paragraphStyle.hyphenationFactor` (can be 0.0 to 1.0), or you *could* try `paragraphStyle.hyphenationFactor = 0` and then `textView.layoutManager.hyphenationFactor = 0.9` (play with the values) to see if you like the results better. However, there will always be "outliers" that look bad.

Comment: @DewinDell - If it is NOT user-editable? You *could* use a hyphenation algorithm... split the string into words... loop through calculating "best fit" hyphenation... and then create individual "text boxes" with balanced spacing between them. Again, though, you'll hit "outliers" -- and, what to do when only a single word fits? Center it? Left-justify it? If you're dead-set on full-justification, I think you'll need to accept the fact that it is going to look bad (which is why full-justification is so strongly discouraged to begin with).

Comment: @DonMag I'm only using `UITextView` to make the text justified but it is _not_ editable. I am very surprised this isn't supported out of the box. I basically want the CSS `inter-word` justify, but Apple chose `inter-character` by default. I'll try what you suggested though. I appreciate your help and ideas.

Comment: @DonMag it's becoming apparent to me that the way to do this is to implement custom behaviour in one of the TextKit methods. Probably in NSTextLayourManager. I'm reading the docs right now to figure out what needs to be done.

Comment: @DewinDell - ah, it's been a ***long*** time since I worked with html/css... wasn't familiar with `text-justify: inter-word;`. Since you're not intending it to be a user-editable input view, you could always use a `WKWebView`: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZ2UM.png